# catch all route for a specific controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to write a catch all route for my `Admin` controller so I don't have to define a lot of routes.

I was thinking something like this would work:

```
match "/admin(/:action)(/:id)"
```

but obviously not.

Whats the best way to go about this? I only want this for the `Admin` controller nothing else.

Comment: D you have only one Admin Controller which everything is in there? It is not a namespace containing other controllers like for Users: `/admin/users/12/edit`?

Comment: @MrYoshiji Yes just one controller

Comment: Okay so `match "/admin(/:action)(/:id)", controller: 'admin'` may work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this one will work for you:

```
match "/admin(/:action)(/:id)", controller: 'admin'
```

But I am not sure on how it will behaves for the path "/admin" (no params[:action]).

Comment: `/admin` just sent it to the `index` action. Perfect.

Comment: Oh, that's a good default-behavior-and-Rails-black-magic happening again!